# Bi-annual Salesforce MVP Nominations are Open

Tags: discussion, mvp

**Public service announcement:**

The [MVP nominations](https://www.salesforce.com/mvp/nominations.jsp) are open from now until January 8th, 2016 at 5:00 p.m. PST.

Feel free to nominate (or renominate) those who have made an exceptional contribution to the SFSE community. That could be [users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year) or [moderators](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) or anyone else who has helped you on your way.

Comment: There are several users on the first page I'd like to nominate, but can't find their SF User Id's and don't necessarily know their real names. I suspect others may have the same issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: @crmprogdev People who don't want to be found won't be found. Such is the Internet. I think *most* of the top list have provided one or more means of contacting them. Check their "about" page.

Comment: +1 for this is thought .Please take a moment to nominate people who have gone beyond to help this community :).